# Running total when looping through .CSV file

Tags: vbscript

I need to loop through a .csv file and keep a running total of column B for each unique value in column A and then output those to a new .csv file.  I understand how to read through the .csv file and write the output to the new file but I cannot figure out how to keep the running total for each values in column A and write it out at the end.

Input File:

```
Column A     Column B
Report 1     10
Report 2     15
Report 3     5
Report 1     15
Report 3     30
```

The values in Column A are random and can change from file to file.

Comment: A [`scripting.dictionary` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) would be helpful here. You can set the key to the `Column A` value and then add to the `value` of that key with the `Column B` value. Like `If Dict.Exists(<columnA>) Then Dict(<columnA>) = Dict(<columnA>) + <columnB> Else Dict.Add <columnA>, <columnB>` inside your loop.

Comment: If you post the code you have already (edit the question) you'll have much better chance at a useful answer.